# Tooltip for D3 Heatmap canvas

Tags: canvas, d3.js, tooltip, d3heatmap

Here i'm working on [D3 Heatmap with resettable zoom](http://bl.ocks.org/robnagler/e245b69c473da73dfb85), but i want to add tooltip to view the intensity count. With help of [D3 tip](http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js), i tried to add tooltip, but don't know how to get the intensity count from canvas, where the heatmap is drawn as an image data. Please check out my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/NayanaDas/6qmeb7oe/2/).

Code used for adding tooltip:

```
var tip = d3.tip()
.attr('class', 'd3-tip')
.offset([-10, 0])
.html(function (d) {
    return "tooltip";
})
svg.call(tip);

svg.on('mousemove', tip.show);
svg.on('mouseout', tip.hide);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the intensity do the following:

```
var tip = d3.tip()
    .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
    .offset([10, 0])
    .html(function (d) {
        var k = d3.mouse(this);
        var m = Math.floor(scale[X].invert(k[0]));//will give the scale x
        var n = Math.floor(scale[Y].invert(k[1]));//will give the scale y
        return "Intensity Count: " + heatmap[n][m];
    })
```

Working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/h0reyumq/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort. It worked perfectly. Can you please help me with my next question too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34369116/to-integrate-d3-band-zoom-in-d3-heatmap