# To integrate D3 Band zoom in D3 heatmap

Tags: d3.js, zooming, d3heatmap

Here I want to integrate [D3 Band zoom](http://bl.ocks.org/jroetman/9b4c0599a4996edef0ab) in [D3 Heatmap with resettable zoom](http://bl.ocks.org/robnagler/e245b69c473da73dfb85). The red band appears while dragging, but it didn't zoom. I think, there some issue in zoom function, but i couldn't track it yet. Please check out my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/NayanaDas/2f6jmf2k/).

Zoom function:

```
function zoom() {

    //recalculate domains
  if(zoomArea.x1 > zoomArea.x2) {
      x.domain([zoomArea.x2, zoomArea.x1]);
    } else {
      x.domain([zoomArea.x1, zoomArea.x2]);
    }

    if(zoomArea.y1 > zoomArea.y2) {
      y.domain([zoomArea.y2, zoomArea.y1]);
    } else {
      y.domain([zoomArea.y1, zoomArea.y2]);
    }

    var t = svg.transition().duration(750);
    t.select(".x.axis").call(scale[X]);
    t.select(".y.axis").call(scale[Y]);
}
```

[image]

Please suggest a method to resolve it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: ```t.select(".x.axis").call(scale[X]);``` won't work at all because you are not calling a function but an object. I will have a look at your fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a potential canvas-based solution.

You can modify your zoom function to force a redraw using only a sub rectangle of the image with

```
context.drawImage(image,sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight);
```

Then give `sx,sy` top-left coordinates of your selection rectangle, and `sWidth,sHeight` width and size of selection rectangle.

`dx,dy,dWidth,dHeight` are constant in your case, `0,0,canvasWidth,canvasSize`

You will probably need to modify createImageObj to also use `drawImage` rather than `putImage`. I am not familiar with `canvas` so you need to check this point.

Hope this helps.

For reference, MDN docs on [`drawImage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage)

Comment: Up-voted, as it helped partially. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a potential solution.

First, ditch the canvas.

Use the following structure instead :

```html
<svg>
  <g id="x axis">
    // ...
  </g>
  <g id="y axis">
    // ...
  </g>
  <svg id="imageContainer" viewbox="0 0 heatmapDim[0] heatmapDim[1]">
    <image xlink:href="yourHeatmap"/>   
  </svg>
</svg>
```

The key here is to use the viewBox attribute of the second `<svg>` (#imageContainer). This will allow you to define a subwindow on your image

And modify your zoom

```js
function zoom() {
        
     //recalculate domains
      var x0,x1,y0,y1;
  
      if(zoomArea.x1 > zoomArea.x2) {
          x0 = zoomArea.x2;
          x1 = zoomArea.x1;
        } else {
          x0 = zoomArea.x1;
          x1 = zoomArea.x2;
        }
        
        if(zoomArea.y1 > zoomArea.y2) {
          y0 = zoomArea.y2
          y1 = zoomArea.y1;
        } else {
          y0 = zoomArea.y1;
          y1 = zoomArea.y2;
        }
        
        
        d3.select("#imageContainer").attr("viewBox",x0 + " " + y0 + " " + x1 + " " + y1);
       
  }
```

That should do the trick, haven't tested it thought, your fiddle is quite large and that doesn't help.

Comment: Sorry, I cant drop the canvas, i really need it. Without ditching it, how can I make it possible?

Comment: Ah ok, sorry about that. I have found an other way, I will make a separate answer because it is completely different